# When run npm test in reactjs part of ASP.NET Boilerplate Web Application SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, testing, aspnetboilerplate, abp, craco

I'm use ASP.NET Boilerplate Web Application for my project when i want to run the default test for frontend of project with npm test facing this error:

```
     FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\Taratech\safe\reactjs\node_modules\antd\es\spin\style\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import '../../style/index.less';        
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Loading/index.tsx:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Loadable/index.tsx:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.975s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

then when i add   `"type": "module",` to package.json facing this error:

```
D:\Taratech\safe\reactjs\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\config.js:46
    const config = require(configFilePath);
                   ^

craco\craco\lib\config.js not supported.
craco.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename craco.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in D:\Taratech\safe\reactjs\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS 
(using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at loadCracoConfig (D:\Taratech\safe\reactjs\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\config.js:46:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Taratech\safe\reactjs\node_modules\@craco\craco\scripts\test.js:20:21) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Dear often this caused by NodeJs Version,
If you are using latest version of abp consider using the last version of NodeJs and Consider using yarn instead of npm

Good luck